# Why my BottomNavBar doesn't update when I use Obx wherease it works fine when I use Getbuilder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, state-management

I have started learning getx lately, for a moment I thought that I understood how it works, but I get stack to this issues, where my navigator bar upated really fine when I use **Getbuilder** and it doesn't work when I use **Obx**, actually it work only when I use hotreaload otherwise it doesn't work, why? this is my controller

```
class DashboardController extends GetxController{
      RxInt navBarIndexController= 0.obs;
    
      void navbarController(int index){
        this.navBarIndexController= RxInt(index);
        print(index);
      }
    }
```

```
   class DashBoard extends StatelessWidget {
     static const String PageName = "/dashboard";
      List<Item> ItemsList = [
        Item(wilaya: 'Setif', itemname: 'Table de menage', ProfilePicturePath: 'assets/images/zahrou.jpg', surname: 'Soualem', FavCounts: 300, ImagePath: 'assets/images/posters.jpg', name: 'Zahreddine'),
        Item(wilaya: 'Alger', itemname: 'Trainers', ProfilePicturePath: 'assets/images/zahrou.jpg', surname: 'Benaouda', FavCounts: 10, ImagePath: 'assets/images/trainers.jpg', name: 'Chouaib'),
        Item(wilaya: 'Oran', itemname: 'Bags', ProfilePicturePath: 'assets/images/zahrou.jpg', surname: 'Djidel', FavCounts: 378, ImagePath: 'assets/images/postersin.jpg', name: 'Akrem'),
        Item(wilaya: 'Annaba', itemname: 'Phone', ProfilePicturePath: 'assets/images/zahrou.jpg', surname: 'Djemmal', FavCounts: 400, ImagePath: 'assets/images/Angle.jpg', name: 'Islem'),
     ];
   
      final controller = Get.put(DashboardController());
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
       double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
       return     Obx(() => Scaffold(
            
               bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                 type:BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                 onTap: controller.navbarController ,
                 currentIndex: controller.navBarIndexController.value,
                 selectedItemColor: Colors.green,
                 unselectedItemColor: Colors.black ,
                 showSelectedLabels:false,
                 showUnselectedLabels: false,
                 items: [
                   BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined,),title:Text("home")),
                   BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_outline,),title:Text("home")),
                   BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined,),title:Text("home")),
                   BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.bell,),title:Text("home")),
                   BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined,),title:Text("home")),
                 ],
               ),
               
             ),
       );
         }
   
   }
```

This is where the problemm appears

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this

```
this.navBarIndexController= RxInt(index); // not the way to update values of Rx types
```

to this

```
navBarIndexController.value = index;
```

Or another shorthand way where you don't have to use `.value`

```
navBarIndexController(index);
```